# Dropbox image upload type not supported

Tags: support, bug, images, imgur

I was editing a post with a primary intent to include pictures in the post that had been linked to by a low rep user. ([The post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/74990/revisions) appears to have been deleted). Normally this process is very easy - copy the URL, and paste it in the "From the Web" tab of the image uploader. However, it rejected this Dropbox image with the error message:

> "Failed to upload image; the format is not supported"

I downloaded the pictures, which worked fine, but wasn't near as convenient.

This was the URL for one of the Dropbox pictures. https://www.dropbox.com/s/l4mqh9ji0p4sdu7/Screen%20Shot%202012-12-15%20at%2011.20.25%20PM.png

Is this happening because it is a secure HTTP request or is there a way to mitigate this problem in the future?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears the imgur upload service isn't finding the embedded image, but there appears to be a somewhat simple workaround.

- change **www** to **dl** after the https://
- append **?dl=1** to the URI

I'm not sure if stack exchange will want to implement this systematically (or even can implement this) or if opening a ticket with imgur to better scrape a dropbox hosted image would work.

https://dl.dropbox.com/s/l4mqh9ji0p4sdu7/Screen%20Shot%202012-12-15%20at%2011.20.25%20PM.png?dl=1

Comment: This no longer appears to work. The image upload simply reports invalid url. =(

Comment: @J.Steen Bummer - it might be time to ask a new question, but I'll check to see if there's another tweak that might work now that things have changed...

Comment: Forcing the right-click menu to show, and selecting "Copy image URL" (in Chrome) and using that URL works. But such a workaround. And you'd need to actually go to the dropbox image in question.